# Prove or disprove the 2 norm for any column of an orthogonal matrix is smaller or equal to 1

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, orthogonal-matrices

Is this a true statement or under some condition this is a true statement? I have try a dozen of MATLAB randomly generated real value square matrix, than take the QR decomposition to them, and all of orthogonal matrix obtained from QR decomposition seems satisfied this property, but I don't understand why this happened. Could anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint.* When $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix, how is the $j$-th diagonal element of $Q^TQ$ related to the entries of the $j$-th column of $Q$?

Comment: OK, I see, so the diagonal entries of $Q^TQ$ will give the jth column dot with itself, and it is just the 2 norm of the each column in this cases since the diagonal entries is just one?

Comment: *" it is just the 2 norm of the each column in this cases **since** the diagonal entries is just one"*. That isn't very accurate. The squared norm of the $j$-th column is the $j$-th diagonal entry of $Q^TQ$. This is true for all real matrices $Q$, not just for the orthogonal ones. This fact itself does not guarantee that the norm is $1$. However, as $Q$ is orthogonal, we have $Q^TQ=I$. Therefore the $j$-th diagonal entry of $Q^TQ$ is also equal to $1$ and it follows that all columns of $Q$ are unit vectors.

Comment: OK, I see, it make sense for me now, thank you.